# How do I launch modal form UL item

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

How can make any of the li items launch modal when clicked. I'm attempting to log to console when the a is clicked but it does not log to console. All of the code can also be seen at this codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/KKPJQQg

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".a");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  console.log("item clicked");
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you save the collection of all `a` inside the `btn` variable. The collection doesn't have an `onclick` function, so there is no effect, when you click one of the buttons. You have to set the `onclick` function for each `a` inside the `btn` collection. For example:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".a");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    console.log("item clicked");
  }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a>some other anchor tag</a>
<ul>
  <li><a class="a" href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```